# How do I draw a line at the top of a div for a home bar?

Tags: html, css

```
.topbar {
background-color: white;
position: fixed;
margin: -10%;
z-index: 10;
height: 10%;
width: 110%;
}
```

This is my code for my div, it is supposed to be a home bar. I want it to have an orange line at the top as StackOverflow does. I am a beginner and I don't know how to do this. Thank you for helping in advance!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add

```
border-top: 3px solid #f48024;
```

Comment: You even gave me the color! Thank you! (but orange was just un example hahahaha)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
.topbar {
background-color: white;
position: fixed;
margin: -10%;
z-index: 10;
height: 10%;
width: 110%;
border-top: 1px solid Orange;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`border-top: 3px solid orange;` should do it